# Why do my CSS links require a ?vh=# in order to update on my Cloudflare website?

Tags: html, caching, cloudflare

I am having a bit of an odd problem that I have never experienced before. I have checked the net and asked someone but could not find the answer. When I work on my website and publish it, the CSS will not update unless I put a ?vh=1 at the end of the CSS links. The [site](https://davidpicarazzi.com/quorum-test-server/dist/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/main.css?vh=1.5">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 819px)" href="../dist/css/_tablet/index-tablet.css?vh=1.2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 414px)" href="../dist/css/_mobile/index-mobile.css?vh=1.7">
    <link rel="icon" href="../assets/images/quorum_favicon.svg" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
    <title>Quorum / Home</title>
</head>
```

Here's an example of what the head looks like on all my pages. I am working on the responsiveness and what I have to do every time is change the number after the  `?vh=`  and it's slowing down my workflow super fast. I won't even know which link I have to change either so I am spending more time figuring that out than actually styling the site. Is this normal to happen?

EDIT: I also wanted to mention I have cleared the cache several times and done hard refreshes so that has not worked either.

Comment: Now that you know it's a caching problem, it'd be really good to know 
A. Whether the ?vh= at the end had anything to do with behavior or just coincided with forcing CF to update its cache, and 
B. What the what? Could you pls share some docs about that syntax? I'm kindof a graybeard, and I've never seen CSS links build that way, with what looks like HTTP params, and I'd love to learn if that's something legit I should understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudflare (what you are using) has a server side cache as well, see https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-Customizing-Cloudflare-s-cache. Clearing the client side cache in your browser has no affect on the server side cache used by cloudflare. Specially check https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516#h_a01982d4-d5b6-4744-bb9b-a71da62c160a to see that CSS files are cached. Configure your cloudflare application/installation/host to change the caching settings in a way you like.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I was doing something wrong and this is a new topic for me. I now will know the answer to this problem for a life time! I can't thank you enough!